# Filter array with hooks explanation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

Can someone explain to me why this is not filtering toDoList

```
const handleDelete = e => {
    const { id } = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
    toDoList.filter(element => element._id !== id);
    setToDoList([...toDoList]);
  };
```

While this is:

```
const handleDelete = e => {
    const { id } = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
    setToDoList(toDoList.filter(element => element._id !== id));
  };
```

Comment: 1st filter returns a new array (not mutates ecisting object) but filtered value not assigned anywhere, it's lost - original used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind that is [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns the new filtered array at the end. Read from the documentation:

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

In the second example you are passing it to `setToDoList` meanwhile in the first, the code is just calling it but not assigning to a variable.

Consider the following:

```js
const toDoList = [{id: 1, name: 'first'}, {id: 2, name: 'second'}];
const id = 1;

toDoList.filter(element => element.id !== id);
console.log('original toDoList:', toDoList);

const result = toDoList.filter(element => element.id !== id);
console.log('filtered result:', result);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: That's a clear and detailed explanation. Thx! I'll look more into the docs next time.

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` does not updates the reference array but returns a new array so in first scenarion, you are filtering and not saving the filtered output and hence setting same value again while in second scenarion, you are passing return filtered values to setter